# limits of the differential of $\sqrt{1-\cos x}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

How do I find the left and right limits as $x$ goes to $0$ of the differential of the function $y = \sqrt{1 - \cos(x)}$? When I put the equation into Wolfram Alpha, the left limit was $- 1/\sqrt2$ and the right limit was $1/\sqrt{2}$ but I don't understand how these are the answers.

Comment: Here is a hint. $|\sin \frac {x}{2}| = \sqrt {\frac {1-\cos x}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sqrt{1-\cos x}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$$
clearly from this we can see that $\cos x<1$ so $x>0$